# sim serial number vs imsi

Tags: android, telephonymanager

I am building an android app that will be licensed on the user's SIM card. There are 2 possible values that I can check against:

1. SIM SERIAL NUMBER: `TelephonyManager.getSimSerialNumber();`
2. IMSI: `TelephonyManager.getSubscriberId();`

As I do not want to use both, I guess that there is no actually difference to rely to the one or to the other. Am I right or is there something that I am missing here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you want.

If the license works by checking that the serial number matches your database as an example.

If the user installs your app and the sim card serial is stored in your DB, if the user removes the sim card and inserts a new sim card, the license will fail as your DB doesn't store the serial for the new sim card.

If you get based on the IMSI number then the license will be with the device, so even if user replaces the SIM the license will still pass as your using the device ID.

Note though I don't know whether the SIM serial will work or how it will handle devices that do not have SIM such as CDMA devices in the US.

Comment: `IMSI` number is not based on the device, but on the SIM card. If the user replaces the SIM card with a new one, the new SIM will have a new `IMSI`.

Answer (score -1):

ICCID (SIM Serial) is the serial number of the SIM. It is unique per SIM.
IMSI is a SubsID. It is actually a network ID.

More reference: https://m.blog.naver.com/framkang/220363349346